# Failure in numerical experiment of singular integral equation?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-integration

Define 
\begin{equation}
G(t,s) := - \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[\ln \left(4 \sin^2 \frac{t-s}{2}\right) -1 \right] \quad (t \neq s)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
K_0 \Psi := \int^{2\pi}_0 G(t,s) \Psi(s) ds, \quad t \in (0,2\pi)
\end{equation}
It is a classical result in singular boundary integral equation (SBIE) that,
\begin{equation}
K_0 \hat \psi_n = \frac{1}{\vert n \vert} \quad \textrm{for} \ n \neq 0 
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
K_0 \hat \psi_0 = \hat \psi_0 
\end{equation} 
where the functions
\begin{equation}
\hat \psi_n = e^{int} , \quad t \in [0,2\pi], \quad n \in \mathbb{Z} .
\end{equation} 
However, when we operate it in MATLAB, we will see, for example, (Notice: the following programs are provided by a friend.)

1.

```
 clear all
    clc
    t1 = 0; t2 = 2 * pi;
    s1 = 0; s2 = 2 * pi;
    c = -1/(2*pi);
    fun = @(t,s)c*(log(4 * (sin((t-s)./2)).^2 )- 1 ).*(exp(i*s).*exp(i*t));
    A = integral2(fun,t1,t2,s1,s2)
```

The result read

```
A =

      NaN +    NaNi
```

2.

```
clear all
clc
t1 = 0; t2 = 2 * pi;
s1 = 0; s2 = 2 * pi;
c = -1/(2*pi);
fun = @(t,s)c*(log(4 * (sin((t-s)./2)).^2 )- 1 ).*(exp(2*i*s).*exp(i*t));
A = integral2(fun,t1,t2,s1,s2)
```

The result also read

```
A =

      NaN +    NaNi
```

According to the classical result in (SBIE) and orthogonal expansion theory, the numerical results of 1,2 should be 1,0, respectively. This gives a contradiction.

> ***Question:*** **Is there any wrong in the program? If the program is right, how can we explain the contradiction between numerics and
>   theory?**

**My Guess:**  Since the logarithmic singularities exist at $ t = s $ in $ G(t,s) $, the MATLAB break down when it begin calculating the double integral near the diagonal line $ t =s $.

Notice that the calculation of double integral above is necessary in Petrov-Galerkin method approximately solving Symm's integral equation of one dimension with Fourier basis.  If my guess is right, then **we must not obtain a good numerical realization for Petrov-Galerkin method with Fourier basis into Symm's integral equation?**

---

---

**Edit:**

We test the example by dividing the square into two triangles, that is, the logarithmic singularities at $ t =s $ is seperating to the boundary. Now

1.

```
clear all
clc
t1 = 0; t2 = 2 * pi;
s1 = 0; s2 = 2 * pi;
c = -1/(2*pi);
fun = @(t,s)c*(log(4 * (sin((t-s)./2)).^2 )- 1 ).*(exp(i*s).*exp(i*t));
A = integral2(fun,t1,t2,s1,@(t) + t);
B = integral2(fun,t1,t2,@(t) + t ,s2);
C = A + B
```

The result read

```
C =

   6.8971e-11 + 7.8594e-16i
```

2.

```
clear all
clc
t1 = 0; t2 = 2 * pi;
s1 = 0; s2 = 2 * pi;
c = -1/(2*pi);
fun = @(t,s)c*(log(4 * (sin((t-s)./2)).^2 )- 1 ).*(exp(2*i*s).*exp(i*t));
A = integral2(fun,t1,t2,s1,@(t) + t);
B = integral2(fun,t1,t2,@(t) + t ,s2);
C = A + B
```

The result read

```
C =

   2.6390e-09 + 2.4980e-16i
```

We can see that, there exist big deviation between numerical results and answer. The domain decomposition can only provide a bad result.

Comment: Your guess is probably right, Matlab has no idea that your integral has a singularity in your domain, you can try to split the integration domain so that the singularity is on the boundary as explain in [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/singularity-on-interior-of-integration-domain.html). But, for this kind of singularities, we know which quadrature to use see [Kress, 1991](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089571779190068I).

Comment: @  Zoïs Moitier Thank you for comment. The method in link is not so applicable( See details in the Edit ). As to the quadrature method in [Kress,1991], it applies intepolation into the quadrature needed in realization of Petrov-Galerkin method. Actually, the numerical method now is Galerkin-Collocation method which corresponds to another style of error analysis (another story). For myself, I need numerical examples to support the error analysis of (PG). Now, I feel pessimistic on the practical value of  pure (PG) on (SBIE).